# issue with code in 'class-wp-query.php' file

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, arguments

I have this bit of code:

```
    // If a post number is specified, load that post
    if ( $q['p'] ) {
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID = " . $q['p'];
    } elseif ( $q['post__in'] ) {
        $post__in = implode(',', array_map( 'absint', $q['post__in'] ));
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN ($post__in)";
    } elseif ( $q['post__not_in'] ) {
        $post__not_in = implode(',',  array_map( 'absint', $q['post__not_in'] ));
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID NOT IN ($post__not_in)";
    }
```

but when it is run I get these errors:

**Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array on line 1918**

**Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed on line 1918**

It's referring to this line: 
$post__in = implode(',', array_map( 'absint', $q['post__in'] ));

How can i fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting user data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters.

Comment: Self explanatory - `$q['post__in']` is not an array.  `print_r($q['post__in']);`

Comment: This is WordPress core code. `/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php`, lines 1912-1923 to be specific. You shouldn't modify this unless you're a core contributor.

Comment: The fact that there is even a line 1918 tells me it's crap.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that's an arbitrary assessment of code quality. It's definitely a warning sign of poor quality, but there are plenty of decent reasons to make a file that long.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I also try to limit my files to 1917 lines or fewer. ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Needs to be a round number so I'm under 1900, kind of OCD. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Something is querying WordPress for posts and passing in incorrect parameters. Specifically, the passed in `post__in` parameter needs to be an array of integer values. Right now, something else is being passed in.

If you've written custom code recently (specifically something with `get_posts()`, `WP_Query`, etc.), try undoing those changes until it works again. Otherwise, try deactivating plugins and/or themes one by one until it works again.